# 4 navlinks needs to close all content and open its own

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have an almost working script but I don't understand scripting too good to make it work on all links.

When you have a look at my fiddle, and you click on the **first two** links, all work fine.
When you click on the other two ones the other content fields don't close. I need to close all, open just one..

http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/8y7Sr/100/

This is a part of the script:

```
$('#activator-werkwijze').click(function(){
    $('#overlay-werkwijze').fadeIn('fast',function(){
        $('#box-werkwijze').animate({'bottom':'0px'},800);
    });
     $('#box-bureau').animate({'bottom':'-600px'},800,function()
             {
        $('#overlay-bureau').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

i actually don't need the overlay

Comment: there is some error on this script: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/8y7Sr/104/

Answer (score 0):

This is the script which works, (the overlay is useless) jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/126/